# Using one fragment and an adapter with changing data

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am building a simple file manager in Android using fragments. I used a single fragment that hosts a listView and created a custom adapter to feed data to it. When user changes directory, the adapter gets the content of new directory and list gets updated.
However, since I have only **one** fragment, pressing the back button result in app being closed which is undesired. I would like to make the back button act as a "go up to parent directory" when possible and exit the app if the current directory is the root.

The solution I was thinking of is to override the `onBackPressed` in the activity that hosts the fragment but it seems to me sort of a hack. Is there any alternative solution that would be more elegant?

Comment: `onBackPressed` is the way to go.  Why does it seem a `hack`?

Comment: Don't know, maybe because I haven't seen it implemented before.. just wanted to make sure it's ok to do it :)

Comment: The only issue would be to know when a back press `should` close the app.  You may find a `up` icon on the `ActionBar` more preferable but closing when the root folder is shown seems fairly intuitive.